# Make tf.nn.conv2d_transpose in Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

My question is how to make operation of `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` in [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch).

See the example below:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y_val = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 1024)
feats_val = np.random.rand(3, 3, 128, 1024)

y_tf = tf.Variable(y_val)
feats_tf = tf.Variable(feats_val)

y_tor = torch.tensor(y_val)
feats_tor = torch.tensor(feats_val)

y_up_tf = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(y_tf, feats_tf, [1, 64, 64, 128], strides=[1,2,2,1])
```

I want to get the same result than `y_up_tf` using `y_tor` and `feats_tor` in Pytorch.

Comment: What's wrong with `torch.nn.ConvTranspose2D` ?

Comment: This method can‘t specify the filter weights

Answer (score 0):

The functional [conv_tranpose2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d.html#torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d) seems to be what you are looking for. You cannot specify the output shape like you do with the tensdorflow one but rather have to tweak the `output_padding` to get the shape you want, but that is the only difference I think.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
y_up_tor = F.conv_transpose(y_tor, feats_tor, output_padding=(1,1), stride=(2,2))
```

Comment: Yep, It's a potential solution. But it still get the different result in respect to y_up_tf and y_up_tor.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "different results" you get ? With an actual example that would show what you would like to get and what's wrong ?